# Validate Certificate Chain with Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, validation, ssl, bouncycastle, x509

I need to write a Java program using Bouncy Castle to validate certificate chains. By searching through the reference, I find the cert.path package, and I tried to use it. [Here](http://pastebin.com/4m8Y2y9U) is the code I have written. However, when I run it with Facebook certificate chain as input, I got a weird behaviour. The chain is made of a server certificate, an intermediate CA certificate, and a root self-signed certificate. The validation outcome is ok if the input is:

- Server and CA cert
- Server cert
- CA cert and Server

The validation failed, with unhandled extensions key usage and basic constraints, if the input is the whole certificate chain. Can someone point me out how can I correctly validate a chain using also system root certificates? 
I found a lot of examples online using java.security package, but since I'm comparing different libraries to validate certificates, I would like to perform the task using only Bouncy Castle packages, if possible.

Thank You,

Nicholas

Comment: BouncyCastle implements the Java security API. Use that and avoid using BouncyCastle specific APIs as far as is possible. This gives you the ability, in the future, to switch back to native Java or even to any security provider with no code changes.

Comment: So, "BouncyCastle implements Java Security API" means that it uses the same class structure of Java Security or that Java Security is just a set of abstract classes and interfaces which are implemented by specific API like BouncyCastle? However, my target is testing Certificate Chain Validation in Java, hence using BouncyCastle because it's well-known as a cryptographic library for Java, but if you tell me that Java Security API are commonly used to perform this task, maybe I could switch to them.

Comment: An API is just that - a set of `public` methods/datastructures that you can use. The implementation can then be chosen later. Hibernate is a "well known" ORM library for Java - but everyone would tell you to use JPA and then plug hibernate in as an implementation rather than use Hibernate directly. For something as basic as x.509 certificate chain validation you should not even need to plug in BouncyCastle. See [JCA](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html).

Comment: See also the [PKI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html) API.

Comment: JCA was the missing step! Now I rewrite the program using Java Security Engine classes with BouncyCastle provider, and everything seems to work fine. Sorry but it's the first time I see a library used as provider for other APIs. Thank You very much for your hints :)

Comment: np! That's why we're all here... This is a very common pattern in all of Java EE - almost everything is an API with a reference implementation as well as other implementations.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63020771/how-to-use-bouncycastle-to-get-the-certification-path-between-a-root-ca-and-an-e